# WiFi only working and connecting when in Recovery Mode

Tags: wifi, mac-mini, recovery

The WiFi of my Mac Mini (Late 2014, Big Sur) will not connect, unless in Recovery Mode. When I boot it normally, it shows the WiFi symbol with an exclaimation mark over it. I cannot turn on the WiFi switch, it doesn't react when I click it.

[image: Screenshot of WiFi]

I tried adding a new connection via the Network Preferences, but it doesn't work either. After clicking on "Create" no WiFi connection is added and nothing changes in the list. It simply won't add anything. I can add other types of connections, but not a WiFi type.

[image: Screenshot of WiFi Nwtwork Preferences]

When I boot using the recovery mode however, I'm able to click on the WiFi symbol, see all connections in the vicinity and select my router. I'm able to click it, enter the password and it connects. But as soon as I restart it normally, it goes back to not working.

[image: RM Screenshot]

Feels like the WiFi itself is still alive and working, but something goes wrong as soon as I boot. It stays the same in across all user accounts. Any ideas how I can figure this out?

<s>**Edit:**</s>

After re-installing Big Sur:

- at first nothing changed
- I tried to figure out what might be causing it (3rd party software perhaps) and had to restart it a couple of times.
- WiFi-symbol suddenly came to life and was on (not sure why, I didn't do anything specific and I didn't turn it on)
- Exclaimation point is gone, but I don't know if this is permanent, I'm to afraid to re-start at this point, so I'll wait.
- the WiFi list however is empty and it won't connect if I enter the credentials manually
- still can't add WiFi connection via Network Preferences

[image: WiFi won't connect]

**Edit 2:**

After restarting, it's back to the previous state, exclaimation mark and not reacting.

Other things I've tried with no change:

- SMC & NVRAM reset
- restart router
- boot in safe mode
- re-install Big Sur

**EtreCheck Report:**
https://pastebin.com/CqWKE5cd

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling macOS over the existing system? This will not delete your data.

Comment: I haven't tried that yet, for exactly that reason haha. What is the best way to do this, via the recovery mode screen? I guess I'll just backup everything.

Comment: I would make a backup yes, but it's going to behave like doing an OS install so it shouldn't cause issues. Use recovery mode and click directly to "Reinstall macOS Big Sur"

Comment: (and by OS install I meant to type OS upgrade)

Comment: I clicked on "Reinstall macOS Big Sur" and it did a re-install. Nothing has changed though. Still the same issue unfortunately.

Comment: Try creating a new "Location" in the Network preferences, and use that instead of the "Automatic" location.

Comment: Have you try boot in Safe mode (push shift key at boot)?

Comment: @GordonDavisson: Tried this, and it still won't add a new WiFi connection. Stays exactly the same.

Comment: @Jean_JD Safe mode is the same as regular mode.

Comment: And after Reset Smc, Reset Nvram?

Comment: @Jean_JD: Ok, I went ahead and tried both SMC and NVRAM reset and still no change. I also restarted the router and nothing.

Comment: You can scan your Mac with Etrechek.

Comment: @Jean_JD: Thanks for the suggestion, it hasn't found any major issues, a few minor ones. Should I post the entire report?

Comment: Yes you can do this with a Pastebin link.

Comment: @Jean_JD: Ok, added the report.

Comment: There is no visible problem. Can you try share the wifi from your phone, for example, just to verify if the problem is from the Mac or the box?

Comment: I tested the wifi from my phone and it works with other devices, however not with the mac. Mac still just displaying the exclamation mark and not reacting at all. All other devices can connect to the router as well, so I think this is just with the Mac alone.